# Spring-Boot-jdbcTemplate object not initialized

Tags: spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am a beginner to Spring Boot/MVC. I have been trying to build a very basic example of querying a table containing master data for doctors.However I am repeatedly getting "java.lang.NullPointerException".Most probably because jdbcTemplate object is not getting initialized.
Some of the other users also faced this issue however in their case the problem was resolved after either including starter-jdbc jar or after removing usage of new operator to create jdbctemplate object.I have already factored these suggestions in my code. Any help on the matter would be appreciated.My code snippets are as following:

***1. application.properties :***

```
server.port=8181

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_sample_schema
spring.datasource.username = qwerty
spring.datasource.password = qwerty
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
debug=true
```

***2. Test123Application.java***

```
package com.example;
....all imports...

@SpringBootApplication
public class Test123Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test123Application.class, args);        
    }
}
```

***3.Testcontroller.java***

```
package com.example.controller;
 ....all imports...

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
     public String  demofunction(){
      return "dummytemplate";
   }

    @RequestMapping("/default")
     public String demofunction2(Model model){
        Docrepo docrepo = new Docrepoimpl();
        List<Docmaster> listContact = docrepo.list();
        model.addAttribute("listContact", listContact);
        return "dummytemplate2";
 }  
}
```

***4. Docrepoimpl.java***

```
package com.example.repository;
----all imports---

    @Configuration
    @Repository
    public class Docrepoimpl implements Docrepo{

        @Autowired 
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


        public void adddoctor(Docmaster doc){

            String sql = "INSERT INTO docmastertable (docid,name,yoe,speciality,degree,college,hospital,regno)"
                         + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, doc.getdocid(), doc.getname(),doc.getyoe(), doc.getspeciality(),doc.getdegree(),doc.getcollege(),doc.gethospital(),doc.getregno());
        }

        public List <Docmaster> list(){
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM docmastertable";

            if(jdbcTemplate != null)
                System.out.println("jdbc seems ok...");
            else 
                System.out.println("jdbc is null...");

            List<Docmaster> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new  RowMapper<Docmaster>() {

                @Override
                public Docmaster mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Docmaster doc = new Docmaster();     
                    doc.setdocid(rs.getString("docid"));
                    doc.setname(rs.getString("name"));
                    doc.setyoe(rs.getInt("yoe"));
                    doc.setspeciality(rs.getString("speciality"));
                    doc.setdegree(rs.getString("degree"));
                    doc.setcollege(rs.getString("college"));
                    doc.sethospital(rs.getString("hospital"));
                    doc.setregno(rs.getString("regno"));     
                    return doc;
                }    
            });  
            return listContact;     
        }
    }
```

5. Error Dump:

   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
       at com.example.repository.Docrepoimpl.list(Docrepoimpl.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
       at com.example.controller.TestController.demofunction2(TestController.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
   ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data: Injected repository is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067559/spring-data-injected-repository-is-null)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you are creating the repo directly in your controller class with a `new` statement. I'd recommend to also inject your Repo into your controller class by creating a local member and annotate it with `@Autowired`. If you don't want to follow this way you can also ask the `Context` to return a ready to use bean.

Comment: Thanks , your suggestion worked. But I am slightly baffled.Can you help me figure out why should JdbcTemplate object be concerned about how repo object is being created. I mean to say why is it that if we choose to autowire jdbctemplate then we have to necessarily autowire repo object ?

Comment: The problem is that all your Spring annotaion mapping is not executed when you just create an object via new. So in that case jdbcTemplate will just be null and therefore failing if you try to call something. I recommend you to read the first few chapters of Spring in Action by Craig Walls.

Comment: OK noted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It always happens when you try to access Spring class that are not managed by the Spring Boot framework AKA the Spring boot container.

With the following line you can get any spring boot class for which the @Autowired does not work.

Here is a class that i used to access JdbcTemplate without @Autowired.

```
public class MysqlServiceJava {

// You don't need @Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public MysqlServiceJava() {

    // Get JdbcTemplate through Context container AKA !! THE MAGIC !!
    jdbcTemplate = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);

}

public List<Integer> findAllEasyId(){

    List<Integer> Ids = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql = "SELECT id FROM master_table";
    jdbcTemplate.query(

            sql, new Object[] {},
            (rs, rowNum) -> new MasterTable(rs.getInt("id"))

    ).forEach(
        masterTable -> 
            Ids.add(masterTable.getId()) // add Id to Ids List array
    );

    return Ids;

}

}
class MasterTable {
private Integer id;

public MasterTable(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MasterTable{" +
            "id=" + id +
            '}';
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Thumbs up if you like =)